# Why is the rotation not zero and the divergence zero in the figures below?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Why is the rotation not zero and the divergence zero in figure 1 and figure 2 below?

[image] Figure 1

[image] Figure 2

Comment: [Cross-posted on Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178739/why-is-the-rotation-not-zero-and-the-divergence-zero-in-the-figures-below). Don't do this again.

Answer (score 3):

You can imagine a flow of water, say, that follows your vector fields. The "stream lines" just flow along parallel to one another without water getting "created" or "destroyed". Hence the divergence is zero. On the other hand, a paper boat on this river would notonly be pulled with the stream, it would also start to rotate because its port side is pushed harder than its starboard side.

Comment: what does created or destroyed mean here?